# Example large scale project using QML?

Tags: qt, qml, qt5, qtquick2

I was searching for a open software project (medium or large scale) that uses QML and could be taken as an example of QML/QtQuick usage in practice. There are indeed a lot of small examples that come with the documentation but are there any actively developed projects?

Plasma Media Center and Qt Media Hub are the two I could find but they seem a little dated or not really maintained (I may be wrong here)

Comment: This is indeed a very interesting question. I was wondering the same. Anyway, it need to be asked at http://forum.qt.io/ and not SO

Comment: Apps for Ubuntu Phone and Sailfish would be good places to look.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Search github.

There is an open source desktop environement that is mostly in Qml and is actively developed :

https://github.com/hawaii-desktop

There is also SDDM which is a smaller project :
https://github.com/sddm/sddm

Finally you could check out : qml-material which implements Google's material UI as QML modules.

https://github.com/papyros/qml-material

---

Edit :

For generically searching the most trending QML projects on GitHub :

https://github.com/trending/qml